# Extracting words from a log file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to extract job id's from a log file, and I'm having trouble extracting them in bash. I've tried using sed.

This is how my log file looks like:

```
> 2018-06-16 02:39:39,331 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend 
> - Running 'list' command.
> 2018-06-16 02:39:39,641 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient                      
> - Rest client endpoint started.
> 2018-06-16 02:39:39,741 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       
> - Waiting for response...
>  Waiting for response...
> 2018-06-16 02:39:39,953 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       
> - Successfully retrieved list of jobs
> ------------------ Running/Restarting Jobs -------------------
> 15.06.2018 18:49:44 : 1280dfd7b1de4c74cacf9515f371844b : jETTY HTTP Server -> servlet with content decompress -> pull from
> collections -> CSV to Avro encode -> Kafka publish (RUNNING)
> 16.06.2018 02:37:07 : aa7a691fa6c3f1ad619b6c0c4425ba1e : jETTY HTTP Server -> servlet with content decompress -> pull from
> collections -> CSV to Avro encode ->  Kafka publish (RUNNING)
> --------------------------------------------------------------
> 2018-06-16 02:39:39,956 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient                      
> - Shutting down rest endpoint.
> 2018-06-16 02:39:39,957 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient                      
> - Rest endpoint shutdown complete.
```

I am using the following code to extract the lines containing the jobId:

```
extractRestResponse=`cat logFile.txt`
echo "extractRestResponse: "$extractRestResponse

w1="------------------ Running/Restarting Jobs -------------------"
w2="--------------------------------------------------------------"
extractRunningJobs="sed -e 's/.*'"$w1"'\(.*\)'"$w2"'.*/\1/' <<< $extractRestResponse"
runningJobs=`eval $extractRunningJobs`
echo "running jobs :"$runningJobs
```

However this doesn't give me any result. Also I notice that all newlines are lost when I print the extractRestResponse variable.

I also tried using this command but it doesn't give me any result:

```
extractRestResponse="sed -n '/"$w1"/,/"$w2"/{//!p}' logFile.txt"
```

Comment: "I notice that all newlines are lost", you need to dbl-quote your `"$extractRestResponse"` variable (most likely). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/^-* Running\/Restarting Jobs -*/,/^--*/{//!p;}' logFile.txt
```

**Explanations:**

- Input lines are echoed by default to the standard output after commands are applied. The `-n` flag suppresses this behavior
- `/^-* Running\/Restarting Jobs -*/,/^--*/`: matches lines starting from `^-* Running\/Restarting Jobs -*` up to `^--*`(inclusively)
- `//!p;`: print lines except those matching the addresses

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '/^-+$/{f=0} f; /^-+ Running\/Restarting Jobs -+$/{f=1}' logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your original substitution:

```
sed -e 's/.*'"$w1"'\(.*\)'"$w2"'.*/\1/' <<< $extractRestResponse
```

by using `@` as the delimiter:

```
sed -n "s@.*$w1\(.*\)$w2.*@\1@p" <<< $extractRestResponse
```

The output is the text between `$w1` and `$w2`:

```
> 15.06.2018 18:49:44 : 1280dfd7b1de4c74cacf9515f371844b : jETTY HTTP Server -> servlet with content decompress -> pull from > collections -> CSV to Avro encode -> Kafka publish (RUNNING) > 16.06.2018 02:37:07 : aa7a691fa6c3f1ad619b6c0c4425ba1e : jETTY HTTP Server -> servlet with content decompress -> pull from > collections -> CSV to Avro encode -> Kafka publish (RUNNING) >
```